# Pass CSS class name to component with Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to NextJS and currently converting a plain ReactJS project.

One thing I don't really get yet is how to properly use CSS.

I have a Button component that takes a standard class plus dynamic class names from the parent component. As you can see the class names are being passed through the prop button class - how do I properly process these class names? Currently it says undefined.

```
<Button buttonClass={"primary__button hero-button"}>Jetzt loslegen</Button>


import React from "react";
import style from "./button.module.scss";

export const Button = ({children, buttonClass, onClick}) => {

    return (
        <button className={style.basic__button + " " + style[buttonClass]} onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
    )

};
```

Comment: can you share your `button.module.scss`? It seems like you are passing buttonClass `primary__button hero-button` to component, do you have such className?

Comment: @Shyam Yes they are inside of this scss file

Answer (score 1):

The provided buttonClass prop can be multiple classNames. You have to be able to handle that.

Here's an example of how to parse this.

```
export const Button = ({children, onClick, buttonClass = ''}) => {

  const css = buttonClass
    .trim()
    .split(' ')
    .map((c) => styles[c]).join(' ')

    return (
        <button 
          className={`${style.basic__button ${css}`} 
          onClick={onClick}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )

};
```

Answer (score 0):

As in ES6, this should also be available:

```
<button className={classnames(styles.basic__button, css)} onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
```